# React form in Rails with validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, reactjs, coffeescript

I learn a ReactJS components and I have a problem with validation
I have this code:

```
# postform.js.cjsx
 @PostForm = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    link: ''
    errors: ''
  valid: ->
    @state.link

  handleChange: (e) ->
    name = e.target.name
    @setState "#{ name }": e.target.value

  handleSubmit: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax
      method: 'POST'
      url: "/posts/"
      dataType: 'JSON'
      data:
        post: {
            link: @state.link
        }
      success: (data) =>
        alert('success')
      error: (data) =>
        errors = data
        alert('error' + data)

  render: ->
    errors =
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2>Errors prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>
              <ul>aaa
              </ul>
            </div>
    React.DOM.form
      className: 'form-inline'
      onSubmit: @handleSubmit
      `[errors]`
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'well'
        React.DOM.div
          className: 'form-group'
          React.DOM.input
            type: 'text'
            className: 'form-control'
            placeholder: 'link'
            name: 'link'
            value: @state.link
            onChange: @handleChange
        React.DOM.button
          type: 'submit'
          className: 'btn btn-primary'
          disabled: !@valid()
          'Send link'
```

How Can I validate link field in view to add bootstrap error-class and put some info about validation problem from Rails?
Payload on post, when is invalid:

```
{"link":["is invalid"]}
```

And another question - How Can I improve my speed with writing ReactJS forms, or other components like simple_form in rails?